# ASP.Net 4 Session expires on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, master-pages

I'm using ASP.Net 4 (Visual Studio 2010 - C#). My session keeps expiring on postback. 
I am setting my session variable in the Page_Init method of the MasterPage. The issue is not a timeout problem.

Comment: Use Fiddler or the equivalent to make sure you're not losing your cookies.

Comment: It happens on your own machine or when deployed, or both?

Comment: please provide more details, I suspect this is a problem in webconfig.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET fails to detect IE10.. please check this..

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Answer (score 0):

looks like issue with post back... how are u doing postback...could you please add details..

public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage

{

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    if(Session["abc"] == null)
    Session["abc"] = "abcd";
}
```

}

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page

{

```
   protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    string x = Session["abc"] as string;

    Response.Write(x);

}
```

}

Comment: public classX oClass
            {
                get
                {
                    return Session["XXX"] as classX;
                }
                set
                {
                    Session["XXX"] = value;
                }
            }

if (oClass == null)
                {
                    oLocalClass = new classX ();
                    oLocalClass.[call  a method that sets it a value ];
                    oClass = oLocalClass;
                }